# Imprimir un resultado fuera de un foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Obtengo el código de una web mediante DOM, que busca la etiqueta h2, una vez encontrado inicia el foreach para reemplazar la palabra por un espacio vacío, ya que solo necesito el "Titulo" para luego imprimirlo en un echo o guardarlo en una variable.

Una vez reemplazado el texto que no ocupo, le dejo un `echo $fin;` y si me lo reconoce, pero no lo puedo usar fuera del foreach y que no muestra nada.

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($sitioweb);
$titulo = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h2'); //Buscamos el tag h2

foreach ($titulo as $texto) {
  $texto->textContent;
  $fin = str_replace("Parece que WhatsApp no está instalado.", "", $texto->textContent);
}
echo $fin;
$errors = libxml_get_errors(); //Limpiamos los errores por si las moscas
```

Cuando mando un echo dentro del foreach lo imprime, pero cuando lo dejo fuera del foreach no lo imprime

[image: Imagen de cuando dejo el echo dentro del foreach]

Intente usar el siguiente código:

```
$json = json_encode($texto->textContent);
echo($json);
```

Arroja el siguiente resultado: "Parece que WhatsApp no est\u00e1 instalado."
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo que debería de imprimir el titulo del grupo.

Comment: Estás declarando la variable `$fin` *DENTRO* del bucle foreach, debido a eso, la variable no está disponible *FUERA* del bucle. Declara la variable `$fin = ""` *ANTES* de entrar en el bucle, luego dentro ya puedes modificarla cuantas veces quieras... y seguirá disponible cuando salgas del bucle. Recuerda que las variables no se pueden utilizar más que en el *scope* en el que están declaradas... es decir, donde la declaras y en cualquier *anidación* interior, pero no puede *"subir"* a un scope mayor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si lo he entendido, pero aquí va mi aporte con un ejemplo de lo que me parece que quieres:

```
// datos de ejemplo
$sitioweb = '
<h2>Título 1</h2>
<h2>Parece que WhatsApp no está instalado. ¡Instálalo de una vez!</h2>
<h2>Título 3</h2>';

// creamos un objeto DOMdocument
$dom = new \DOMDocument();

// Cargamos en contenido HTML agregándole la codificación UTF-8
// para que no de problemas con los acentos y carácteres nacionales
$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">'.$sitioweb);

// Buscamos el tag h2 creando una instancia de la clase DOMNodeList
// que contiene los elementos con el nombre de etiqueta local buscado
$titulo = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h2');

// inicializamos la variable $fin fuera del scope del foreach siguiente
$fin = '';

// recorremos los elementos h2
foreach ($titulo as $texto) {
    // miramos de localizar el texto a eliminar
    $pos = strpos($texto->textContent, "Parece que WhatsApp no está instalado.");
    if ($pos === false) {
       // no encuentra nada
    } else {
        // si lo encontramos lo borramos
        $fin = str_replace("Parece que WhatsApp no está instalado.", "", $texto->textContent);

        // salimos del bucle
        break;
    }
}

// mostramos lo que queda del h2 donde se encontró el texto
echo $fin;
```

El resultado es:

```
¡Instálalo de una vez!
```

Ahora, si lo que quieres es borrar todo el h2 y dejar el resto entonces el bucle deberia ser así:

```
// recorremos los elementos h2
foreach ($titulo as $texto) {
    // miramos de localizar el texto a eliminar
    $pos = strpos($texto->textContent, "Parece que WhatsApp no está instalado");
    if ($pos === false) {
       // agregamos el contenido encerrándolo entre h2
        $fin .= '<h2>'.$texto->textContent.'</h2>';
    } else {
        // si lo encontramos no lo agregamos a nada
    }
}

// mostramos lo que queda sin el texto encontrado
echo $fin;
```

Y su resultado seria:

```
<h2>Título 1</h2><h2>Título 3</h2>
```